# How can I remove Gorilla Glue smudges from a quartz countertop?

Tags: repair, kitchens

I used Gorilla Glue to fix an item and of course there wasn't enough counter protection. I removed as much as possible but now there's smudges of Gorilla Glue.  I am afraid to do more damage! Has anyone else dealt with this issue that could offer a wonderful solution?

Comment: which gorilla glue, gorilla glue makes cyanoacrylate and polyurethane glues. acetone works on both but works a lot better on the former.

Answer (score 3):

Using a "brand new" razor blade will remove the bulk of it. Scrape very gently against the dried glue at a sharp angle. Then use some [**#000 or #0000 steel wool**](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Homax-4-0-12-Pad-Steel-Wool-Super-Fine-Grade-10120000/100212006) to remove the remaining residue. Then wipe the area down well. I wouldn't suggest any harsh chemicals, it might dull the shine. Soap and water with a small amount of rubbing alcohol is about as far as I would go.

[image]

[image]

Comment: If the quartz has a gloss surface, won't the 000 steel wool dull the surface ?

Comment: I use #3 and #4 to clean imperfections on glass windows. It doesn't scratch at all, but it does wear out pretty quick.